# AWS S3 ls number of requests and costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to list all my files in my AWS s3 bucket.

I have a particular structure of files in my bucket, which requires that each file is stored in its own directory. Eg with 3 files:

```
├── dir1
│   ├── file1.txt
├── dir2
│   ├── file2.txt
├── dir3
    ├── file3.txt
```

What will be the number of billed requests if I execute `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket --recursive` ? Will it lead to 1 or 3 requests ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying `ListObjects()` API call will return up to 1000 objects.

Since your bucket contains less than 1000 objects, it will only require **one API call**.

The `LIST` operation is charged at `$0.005 per 1000 requests`.

Listing the bucket does *not* involve a `GET` request.

Comment: Does this mean that it does not matter if the files are in sub folders or if they are at the root of the bucket ?

Comment: I haven't verified this, so am not writing an answer, but based on observation I believe that the CLI will call `ListObjectsV2` with the `Delimiter` parameter, which means that it will recursively traverse the prefixes rather than simply listing keys (note to OP: there are no "folders" in S3, regardless of what it looks like).

Comment: The CLI will call with the Delimiter parameter, but if you specify "`--recursive`" it will omit the parameter, and in this example, make one call to ListObjectsV2

Comment: Behind the scenes, the AWS CLI will retrieve the names of _ALL_ objects unless a `Prefix` is specified. Up to 1000 objects will be returned per API call.